# Select date interval inside WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, where-clause

I'm trying to query a list of loans that have been opened within the past 36 months. I'm also trying to query a count of loans that have been opened within the past 12 months as a separate column.

The query is returning the same values for both columns, how can I get get the count from both 36 month and 12 month intervals without running a separate query?

```
SELECT 
`XDL-NAME`, 
COUNT(distinct`XLN-LOANDATE`) as '36 Month Count',
COUNT(IF(`XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), 1 , NULL)) AS '12 Month Count' 
 from
 LOAN
 JOIN
 DEALER ON `XLN-DLNO` = `XDL-NUM` WHERE `XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 MONTH)

 GROUP BY `XDL-NAME`
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, why do you have a `count(distinct)`?  And why are you counting the date if you are looking for a count of loans?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `count` for `12 months`, change to `sum` like below

```
SELECT 
`XDL-NAME`, 
COUNT(distinct`XLN-LOANDATE`) as '36 Month Count',
SUM(IF(`XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), 1 , 0)) AS '12 Month Count' 
 from
 LOAN
 JOIN
 DEALER ON `XLN-DLNO` = `XDL-NUM` WHERE `XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 MONTH)

 GROUP BY `XDL-NAME`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `XDL-NAME`, 
    count((SELECT `XLN-LOANDATE` WHERE `XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 MONTH))) AS '36 Month Count',
    count((SELECT `XLN-LOANDATE` WHERE `XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH))) AS '12 Month Count',
from
    LOAN
        JOIN
            DEALER ON `XLN-DLNO` = `XDL-NUM` 
GROUP BY `XDL-NAME`
```

What I did was use subqueries to count each interval you wanted. This way they should output with Name, 36 month count, 12 month count all on one line (record).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this query to return the two separate counts:

```
SELECT `XDL-NAME`, 
        COUNT(*) as `36 Month Count`,
        SUM(`XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) AS `12 Month Count`
FROM loan l join
     dealer d
     ON `XLN-DLNO` = `XDL-NUM`
WHERE `XLN-LOANDATE` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 36 MONTH)
GROUP BY `XDL-NAME`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **SUM** like:

```
SUM(IF('2016-12-21' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0)) AS '12 Month Count'
```

**Sample**

```
mysql> SELECT IF('2016-12-21' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0);
+----------------------------------------------------+
| IF('2016-12-21' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF('2015-12-22' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0);
+----------------------------------------------------+
| IF('2015-12-22' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF('2015-12-21' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0);
+----------------------------------------------------+
| IF('2015-12-21' >= NOW() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 1, 0) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  0 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```